# Why Function result is not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render various variables and objects but not sure why the list11 contents are not rendered??
SimpleList() displays fine.
Why console.log("list11", list11) does not display in the console log??

added: I am assuming list11 will have the result of function SimpleList so should display the contents.

```
import React from 'react'

export const Testmap = () => {
    
    const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    const doubled = numbers.map((number) => number * 2);
    console.log("doubled", doubled);
    
    const numbers2 = [19, 18 ,17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10];
    const listItems = numbers2.map((number2) =>
        <li>{number2}</li>
    )
    
    const SimpleList = () => (

        <ul>
            {['a', 'b', 'c'].map(function (item)
            {
                return <li key={item}> {item} </li>
            })}
        </ul>
    )
    const list11 = function SimpleList() {
    
                {['a', 'b', 'c'].map(function (item) {
                    return <li key={item}> {item} </li>
                })}
    }
    console.log(",,,,,,")
    console.log("list11", list11)   ????????? this is not printed on console...WHY??


    return (
        <div>
            
            {/* UL listItems: <ul> {listItems}</ul> */}
            SimpleList : <ul>{SimpleList()}</ul>
            List11:  {list11()}
          List11b:  {list11}
            List11c:  {<list11 />}
          

        </div>
    )
}

export default Testmap;
```

Inspect output is:

```
WDS...
main.chunk.js:838 doubled (5) [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
main.chunk.js:884 ,,,,,,
main.chunk.js:885 list11 ƒ SimpleList() {
    {
      ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(function (item) {
        return /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("li", {
          key: item,
          __self: …
0.chunk.js:77900 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Testmap`.
    in li (at Testmap.jsx:11)
    in Testmap (at src/index.js:13)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:11)
```

Display output is:

```
listItems:
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10

SimpleList :
a
b
c
List11a: List11b: List11c:
```

<<<<<<<< NOTHING IS DISPLAYED of list11 here although I expected to see a print of {list11} contents

> > Neeraj Kumar .. your suggestion worked:

````
    const list11 = function SimpleList2() {
            return(  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>ADDED
                ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(function (item) {
                    return <li key={item}> {item} </li>
                }))
    }
    console.log(",,,,,,")
    console.log("list11", list11())
    ```
console log:
````

list11 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]  as expected !!

```
display output:
```

List11a:  as expected !!
a
b
c
List11b:  >>>> nothing here since () is missing

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do. You're defining SimpleList as a function with `const SimpleList = () => ( ... )` then defining `const list11` as another function (strangely also named `SimpleList`). Did you mean to console log the _calling_ of `list11`? Also, the `list11` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Your `list11` doesn't return anything. put a `return` before using `map` statement.

Comment: You should get `list11 undefined` logged.

Comment: Neeraj .. Appreciate your kind response.. When I edited your suggestions in the code .. it gave multiple errors
```
    const SimpleList = () => (

        <ul>
            {['a', 'b', 'c'].map(function (item) {
                return <li key={SimpleList${item}} > { item } </li>
            })}
        </ul>
    )
    const list11 = function SimpleList2() {
    
                {['a', 'b', 'c'].map(function (item) {
                    return <li key={list11a${item}}> {item} </li>
                })}
    }

Comment: Neeraj .. i edited my original question with your suggestions result!

Comment: Neeraj .. your suggestion for the key does not work. please elaborate

Answer (score 3):

You are defining `list11` as a *function*:

```
const list11 = function SimpleList() {
  // ...
}
```

If you want to log the result of *calling* that function, you have to call it:

```
console.log('list11', list11());
```

...however your function is also not returning anything because there is no `return` statement. If you intended `list11` to just be the map result, you don't need to wrap it in a function:

```
const list11 = ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(item => <li key={item}>{item}</li>);
```

...or if you do want it to be a function (and you're going to change the `console.log` so you're calling the function), make sure you're either using an arrow function that has an expression as the body or if you're using a statement block, add a return statement:

```
const list11 = () => ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(item => <li key={item}>{item}</li>);

// or

const list11 = function() {
  return ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(item => <li key={item}>{item}</li>);
}

// or if you _really_ want to assign it a named function expression and use the verbose syntax

const list11 = function SimpleList() {
  return ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(function (item) {
    return <li key={item}> {item} </li>
  });
}

console.log('list11', list11());
```

Comment: Jacob .. Appreciate your prompt response. However:
- console.log('list11', list11());  result is: List11() UNDEFINED.
- Changed SimpleList to SimpleList2() .. still Undefined in console.log
- I wanted to avoid arrow function and use simpler old syntax as below. Why it will not work??:
    const list11 = function SimpleList2() {
    
                {['a', 'b', 'c'].map(function (item) {
                    return <li key={item}> {item} </li>
                })}
    }

Comment: As I said, you still have to _return_ something from the function.

Comment: I'd also recommend against using a named function in conjunction with a const having a different name. You're giving the thing two names for no reason. I'd do `function SimpleList() { }` or `const SimpleList = function() { }` or `function list11() { }` or `const list11 = function () { }`.